# Field '_id' expected a number but got 'top' in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I already seen this type of questions here but I am not able to reproduce the solution.
I'm trying to get Top BlogPosts from my model in relation with their rating.

```
#models.py
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    _id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True,
                              default='/placeholder.png' )
    
    
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True, help_text="Description Here ")
    rating = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    numReviews = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default=0)
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.createdAt)

class BlogPostReview(models.Model):
    blogpost = models.ForeignKey(BlogPost, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    rating = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default=0)
    comment = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    _id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.rating)
```

Serializer

```
#serializers.py
class BlogPostReviewSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = BlogPostReview
        fields = '__all__'

class BlogPostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    reviews = BlogPostReviewSerializer( many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = BlogPost
        fields = '__all__'

    def get_reviews(self, obj):
        reviews = obj.blogpostreview_set.all()
        serializer = BlogPostReviewSerializer(reviews, many=True)
        return serializer.data
```

Now comes to Views ... Problematic one

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, permission_classes
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated, IsAdminUser
from rest_framework.response import Response
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger

from .models import BlogPost, BlogPostReview 
from .serializers import BlogPostSerializer

@api_view(['GET'])
def getBlogPosts(request):
    query = request.query_params.get('keyword')
    if query == None:
        query = ''

    blogposts = BlogPost.objects.filter(
        title__icontains=query).order_by('-createdAt')

    page = request.query_params.get('page')
    paginator = Paginator(blogposts, 8)

    try:
        blogposts = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        blogposts = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        blogposts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    if page == None:
        page = 1

    page = int(page)
    
    serializer = BlogPostSerializer(blogposts, many=True)
    return Response({'blogposts': serializer.data, 'page': page, 'pages': paginator.num_pages})

@api_view(['GET'])
def getTopBlogPosts(request):
    blogposts = BlogPost.objects.filter(rating__gte=4.0).order_by('-rating')[0:10]
    serializer = BlogPostSerializer(blogposts, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)


@api_view(['GET'])
def getBlogPost(request, pk):
    blogpost = BlogPost.objects.get(_id=pk)
    serializer = BlogPostSerializer(blogpost, many=False)
    return Response(serializer.data)


@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def createBlogPostReview(request, pk):
    user = request.user
    blogpost = BlogPost.objects.get(_id=pk)
    data = request.data

    # 1 - Review already exists
    alreadyExists = blogpost.review_set.filter(user=user).exists()
    if alreadyExists:
        content = {'detail': 'Product already reviewed'}
        return Response(content, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    # 2 - No Rating or 0
    elif data['rating'] == 0:
        content = {'detail': 'Please select a rating'}
        return Response(content, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    # 3 - Create review
    else:
        review = BlogPostReview.objects.create(
            user=user,
            blogpost=blogpost,
            name=user.first_name,
            rating=data['rating'],
            comment=data['comment'],
        )

        reviews = blogpost.review_set.all()
        blogpost.numReviews = len(reviews)

        total = 0
        for i in reviews:
            total += i.rating

        blogpost.rating = total / len(reviews)
        blogpost.save()

        return Response('Review Added')
```

URLs

from django.urls import path
from . import views as views

urlpatterns = [

```
path('', views.getBlogPosts, name="blogposts"),
path('<str:pk>/', views.getBlogPost, name="blogpost"),
path('top/', views.getTopBlogPosts, name='top-blogposts'),
path('<str:pk>/reviews/', views.createBlogPostReview, name="create-review"),
```

]

When I try to load top posts this error comes

```
[21/Jun/2021 21:27:43] "GET /api/blog/top/ HTTP/1.1" 500 165476
[21/Jun/2021 21:27:48] "GET /api/blog/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5256
Internal Server Error: /api/blog/top/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1823, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'top'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\decorators.py", line 50, in handler
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\eCommerce_Projects\remote-hospital\blog\views.py", line 48, in getBlogPost
    blogpost = BlogPost.objects.get(_id=pk)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 424, in get
    clone = self._chain() if self.query.combinator else self.filter(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 941, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 961, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone._filter_or_exclude_inplace(negate, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 968, in _filter_or_exclude_inplace
    self._query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1396, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1415, in _add_q
    child_clause, needed_inner = self.build_filter(
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1350, in build_filter
    condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1196, in build_lookup
    lookup = lookup_class(lhs, rhs)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py", line 25, in __init__
    self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py", line 77, in get_prep_lookup
    return self.lhs.output_field.get_prep_value(self.rhs)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1825, in get_prep_value
    raise e.__class__(
ValueError: Field '_id' expected a number but got 'top'.
[21/Jun/2021 21:27:55] "GET /api/blog/top/ HTTP/1.1" 500 165476
```

Need help to remove this error and any other ways to achieve this functionality and what I'm doing wrong in this code.

Comment: Please add the _full_ error traceback to your question.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat full error traceback added.

Comment: Your `rating` field is a DecimalField and it could be you're passing an integer and Django is expecting a a decimal field (e.g. `4.0` instead of `4`)

Comment: Some other view is being used here than you are showing. The view `getBlogPost` is being called according to the error.

Comment: Changed to `4.0` but It;s not working .. Same `error`

Comment: Yes @AbdulAzizBarkat other views as well , I added them in question. Please take a look.

Comment: @FaisalNazik what view are you trying to access exactly? As I said your view `getBlogPost` is being used, this is likely a problem with your url patterns and the url pattern for `getBlogPost` is matching the one that you are currently trying to access.

Comment: There is difference between getBlogPosts and getBlogPost

Comment: `getBlogPosts `is used for search func

Comment: and `getBlogPost` for all Blog Posts

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I Included all urls from blog app . Please look into as well .

Comment: Well `<str:pk>/` matches `top/` does it not? `top` is a _string_ and so the view `getBlogPost` is being used, which is why you get the error. The solution is order your urlpatterns better or write _better_ and more _descriptive_ urls.

Comment: Ahhhh I got your point  ... Thanks @AbdulAzizBarkat for the help

Comment: But one more thing, Im accessing them with different views then why are colliding eachother ? @AbdulAzizBarkat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will be posting your solution and also some thoughts about your code.

## Main Problem

views.py

```py
@api_view(['GET'])
def getBlogPost(request, pk):
    blogpost = BlogPost.objects.get(_id=pk) ## << HERE >> ##
    serializer = BlogPostSerializer(blogpost, many=False)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

urls.py

```py
path('', views.getBlogPosts, name="blogposts"),
path('<str:pk>/', views.getBlogPost, name="blogpost"), ## << HERE >> ##
path('top/', views.getTopBlogPosts, name='top-blogposts'),
path('<str:pk>/reviews/', views.createBlogPostReview, name="create-review"), ## << SAME PROBLEM HERE >> ##
```

In resume, your trying to pass a  type as pk witch is a _id of your model BlogPost and is a AutoField. Probably changing from  ot  will solve the problem.

## Extras

1. Don't know if models.AutoField is the best approach to hold a Id value.
   Normally I will use something like a [UUID Field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#uuidfield)
2. Normally if your a using some necessary and reusable fields such: id, created_at, updated_at, etc.
   A way to do this is a creation of a BaseModel, normally implemented in yourproject.core app. And use it as your models by inheritance, like this:

core.models.py

```py
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField()
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField()
    #
    # Continue your BaseModel
    #
```

And in your models

```py
class BlogPostReview(BaseModel):
    blogpost = models.ForeignKey(BlogPost, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    rating = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default=0)
    comment = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
   
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.rating)
```

3. A good way to improve your views is using [Class Based Views](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/3-class-based-views/)
4. A neat approach to do gets and filters such:

```py
    BlogPostReview.objects.get(id=pk) 
    BlogPostReview.objects.filter(id=pk)
```

Is using a generic filter class, is implemented in the almost like a serializer class and works great with Class Based Views.  [Generic Filter](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#generic-filtering)

Comment: Yes that was the exact problem, And I already solved that before, btw I Appreciate your effort.  I changed original func from `.get(id=pk) to `.all()`  Because I was just needed a list for that specific url and now this is working fine.  Thanx for posting. @Carlos

Comment: Nice
Glad that your code are running fine @FaisalNazik !!
Thanks for the comment.